# Advantages of using unpack methods to update a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

I am confused if there is a real advantage of updating a dictionary key by using `kwargs`. Follow the example below:

```
def example():
    return {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

Using `kwargs` to update the dict:

```
   {**example(),'b':9}
>> {'a': 1, 'b': 9, 'c': 3}
```

I could also use something like:

```
example['b'] = 9
```

Can someone tell me what is the advantage of using unpack method to update `dict` or indicate me some reading material about it? ESpecially when it comes to nested dict because this is where I saw being used.

Comment: None of you example code uses `kwargs` to update a `dict` — so what is your question exactly?

Comment: @martineau you are right, I updated the code, sorry!

Comment: Is example a function or a dictionary? What are you actually trying to ask?

Comment: `{**example(),'b':9}` is using `kwargs`. The `**example()` is a way of expanding the contents of the dictionary the `example()` call returns into a sequence of `key=value` pairs that are then used to construct a new dictionary composed of them and the pair `'b':9`. Since the key `'b'` appears twice in this sequence, the last one wins. So in the scenario, the advantage is it doesn't need to create a new dictionary if it's not used.

Comment: @martineau but if I have a nested dict in many levels? because that is where I saw been used

Comment: may: Please [edit] your question (again) and ask what you really want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{**example(),'b':9}` creates a new dict by unpacking the dict returned by `example()` and then updating the new dict with the key `b`, while `example['b'] = 9` updates the key `b` of the dict `example` in-place and does not create a new dict.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing `**` unpacking methods with the `**kwargs` function parameter. The `**` just unpacks your dictionary returned by `example()` into key/value pairs and then creates a new dictionary with the additional key/value pair `'b':9` you pass to the dictionary constructor.

If you are just adding one key/value pair at a time then this method wouldn't have too much of a value over just assigning it like `example['b'] = 9`, but if you wanted to merge two dictionaries together into one dictionary then it would be much more efficient to do this `new_dict = {**old_dict, **old_dict1}` then loop through and add each key/value pair from both dictionaries to the new dictionary.
This method only works for Python 3.5 and above for earlier versions use `old_dict.update(old_dict2)`. Here is more [reading](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) about pythons unpacking methods and kwargs as well.

Comment: `new_dict = old_dict.update(old_dict2)` is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: Unless its changed methods from doing [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) I don't think so. Either reply with a helpful comment and show me where I'm wrong or don't.

Comment: `update` doesn't return anything (more precisely, it returns `None`, which means "no meaningful return" in this context). `new_dict` will be `None`, not a `dict` of any kind.